# RxSwift: Observable while a button holds down

Tags: swift, rx-swift

How to create Observable which streams an event repeatedly while a button holds down?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even I was looking for a solution for your question. I got help from RxSwift slack channel.

```
    let button = submitButton.rx_controlEvent([.TouchDown])
      button
        .flatMapLatest { _ in
            Observable<Int64>.interval(0.1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                .takeUntil(self.submitButton.rx_controlEvent([.TouchUpInside]))
        }
        .subscribeNext{ x in print("BOOM \(x)") }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

//prints BOOM 0 BOOM 1 BOOM 2 BOOM 3 BOOM 4 BOOM 5 for every 0.1 seconds
```

And also Check [Interval Documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html).Thanks to @jari of RxSwift slack channel.

Answer (score 2):

To continue on rootcoder response, I had a situation where I had to recognize one longpress greater than three seconds

```
 let signinLongpress = signinButton.rx.controlEvent([.touchDown])
    signinLongpress
        .flatMapLatest { _ in
            Observable<Int64>.interval(3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                .take(1)
        }
        .subscribe(onNext:{ _ in print("do fun stuff only once when longpress detected")})
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```